# Rails 3 default datetime format without UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a new Rails 3 app, and in it I use `DateTime` for a couple of fields, however every datetime field standard has UTC behind it (in a view), like:

```
2010-10-10 16:19:00 UTC
```

How do I get rid of the UTC part?

UPDATE: here's what I have so far:

```
<%= trip.truckleft.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") %>
```

So all I have to do now is put that in a helper, but isn't there a better more universal way?

I looked at some other posts, that suggested creating a `time_formats.rb` in initializers, however I didn't have any success doing that.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Another -- perhaps now preferred -- way is to use [Rails' internationalization and localization support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats). There's a lot to learn in that guide, so the tl;dr version is this:

```
<%= l trip.truckleft, :format => :long %>
```

There are [a few predefined date and time formats](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-US.yml) like `:long` available to you already for English, and you can add your own in `config/locales/en.yml` by following the YAML structure in those examples. If you're not getting heavily into the whole i18n/l10n thing just yet and looking at the `l` method all the time is confusing, you can also use:

```
<%= trip.truckleft.to_formatted_s(:long) %>
```

Comment: Argh, here is [the guide I was trying to link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats). Stack Overflow wouldn't let me post more than one link because my account is new. Sheesh.

Comment: +1 and upvoted to get your rep higher--Stack Overflow needs more people like you

Answer (score 42):

Here is what finally worked for me:

I created a new file in:

`config/initializers/`

named: **time_formats.rb**

and added this to that file:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

Then I saved, restarted the server and it started to work.

Comment: This works for me on 4.1. The advantage of this method is that you often don't need to even add the to_s, most contexts will turn the time into a string automatically. You can also add other formats such as Time::DATE_FORMATS[:date_only] = "%Y-%m-%d" and then use them like so date.to_s(:date_only) - less code than the internationalised version, therefore better if you have no plans to internationalise.

Comment: You just have to add Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" as well, not only the time format ;) Works for me in rails > 4.1

Answer (score 26):

I'm using i18n to format my dates and have this in en.yml:

```
date:
  formats:
    default: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

I wanted to reuse that format for how the models show their dates, so my config/initializers/time_formats.rb contains this:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = lambda { |date| I18n.l(date) }
```

Answer (score 14):

To be exact, you should put these in your initializers:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m-%d-%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"
```

When having datetime, the second one will work (for example: created_at for in models).

Answer (score 1):

You can put the following line at the end of your `config/environment.rb` file:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
```

Answer (score 1):

### for rails 3

add to `config/environment.rb`

```
my_datetime_formats = { :default => '%F %T' } #or any other you like
my_date_formats = { :default => '%F' } #or any other you like

Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(my_datetime_formats)
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(my_date_formats)
```

(the difference from other answers - is `merge!` method)