# change default date format in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to change default date format in Rails. Format should be y/m/d . I add following code into my environment.rb

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.
merge!(:default => '%Y/%m/%d')
```

But it didn't work. How can I change default format? I use rails 2.3.8 version

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694352/rails-3-default-datetime-format-without-utc. Look at jankubr post

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a file to config/initializers with the following code:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%Y/%m/%d"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"
```

Comment: Note, several posts elsewhere suggest that messing with these settings affects what is stored in the database; while it may have been true in earlier versions of Rails, as of 3.2, it seems OK.

Comment: Note: this can also be done in a before_filter in a controller if you let your users select their own date and time formats.

Comment: Note that since Ruby 1.9, the ruby dateformat is `%d/%m/%Y` and needs to be changed for these to fully work

Answer (score 0):

Put that in a file in the config/initializers  and that should work.

Comment: still not working... i add a file in config/initializers and put that code.