# How do I set a default date format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a `:dob` (date of birth) attribute and if I if I call it in a view it appears in a `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Where can I set the default to a `MM-DD-YYYY` or some other variation? I would prefer to have it as "January 28th, 1990" and can do that in the view with `dob.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)` but would prefer to have a default to keep the code in my view a little nicer.

Comment: the same type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145152/change-default-date-format-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# config/initializers/date_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the format by overriding the default date format for ActiveSupport.

In `config/environment.rb` add this line

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => "%m/%d/%Y")
```