# Rails3/jQuery UI Datepicker - Month and day are reversed on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, date, format, jquery-ui-datepicker

(My problem is pretty much the same as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427504/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format-issue-with-initial-value), only that answer does not work in my case.)

---

I'm using the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) in a Rails app with a Postgres db. The default implementation uses a **mm/dd/yy** date format to display the selected date, which is exactly what I want. However, after I save the record to the database, the month and day are reversed - it then displays as **yy-dd-mm**. So selecting 3/11/2012 tries to save as November 3rd instead of March 11th, and a date like 3/31/2012 is not saved at all, because it does not exist.

I've gone down 3 different avenues so far trying to fix this:

1) First attempt was to reformat the text field so the display looked how I wanted:

```
<%= f.text_field :foo, :value => (@model.foo.blank? ? '' : @model.foo.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')), class: "datepicker" %>
```

This displayed 03/31/2012 correctly initially, but still reversed when saving.

2) So next I tried changing the default way that dates are stored, thinking that would get around the problem. As described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303495/change-date-format-in-the-view-to-dd-mm-yyyy), I added the following to **config/locales/en.yml**:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

This did not make any difference at all. Next I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694352/rails-3-default-datetime-format-without-utc) and tried creating **config/initializers/date_formats.rb** with these lines:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

Same as above, no difference.

3) After playing around with lots of combinations, the one thing I found that DID work was specifying the yyyy-mm-dd format in my call to the datepicker plugin - it's the opposite of what I wanted, but at least the dates can be successfully saved. So the datepicker call looks like this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Selecting March 31st from the calendar populates the field with 2012-03-31, and still displays as 2012-03-31 after saving.

But how on earth can I get the datepicker to work with a mm/dd/yy format? I can't imagine that's a difficult thing to do, but what am I missing? Do I have to do something with how the dates are stored in Postgres? (They are specified as date, not datetime.)

Comment: To stop bashing my head against the wall over this, I've just switched my fields to 'text' rather than 'date'. It's not ideal, but it does solve the problem rather simply.

Comment: some times switching is a good solution be it ideal or not. but still for curiosity you may want to know the problem, may be later.

Comment: Rails 3.2.3, Postgresql and Ruby 1.9.3. I had datepicker format set to mm-dd-yy and it was working for a while, but I am going through a refactoring and I can save some dates without a hassle but one date in particular no longer is saved. So I am going to reformat back to yy-mm-dd and I will see what happens.

Comment: Update: I tried the yy-mm-dd format in my datepicker call and I still get "date cannot be blank". I am perplexed, but since there is no other solution I will run a migration to change my data types for dates, too text, as you did ... hopefully I or someone can find a solution.

Comment: i've had pretty much the exact same experience with the same results. what worked for me with Rails 3.0 was the Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default], however, after upgrading to Rails 3.2 this was no longer working. In my case I think the problem boiled down to this: `"01/03/13".to_date.to_s --> "03/01/13"` which seems pretty silly

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on how you are storing data in your database.
If you happen to use *RAW* sql queries you can use `to_date('31 Mar 2012', 'DD Mon YYYY')` in your insert query.

Postgres' `to_date` [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

Now, on your client side, in the jquery date picker you can use

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M-yy', Yourdate);
```

I used DD Mon YYYY because it seems clearer. You can use `mm/dd/yy` format or other formats based on the needs. In those cases, use required ***format***  in postgre's `to_date` function

Kindly note, I havent tested above code. Leave comments if there are any issues or you face any troubles.

*Edit:*

You can use  `Date.parse('2011-06-18')` in your rails view, before inserting data into database and set `formatDate` to `'yy-mm-dd'` in the datepicker.

Comment: I may not be understanding what you're saying, but I tried writing a before_save method to rearrange the date before it's inserted into the database. This sounded like it would work, but for some reason, I still got errors when trying to save any date with a day number over 12. I know this has to be because it's trying to switch the day and month, but I can't figure out where that is happening.

Comment: see in logs the query generated by rails(and the value of date column). so as to know, on what side problem actually is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default date format globally for your database cluster you could also set the [DateStyle](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) [GUC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/acronyms.html) in your `postgresql.conf` and reload:

```
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
```

(Which should be the default anyway.)

Note that this does not influence how dates are displayed in your app. Just how PostgreSQL interprets ambiguous input and some output options of Postgres.

---

If you check the `datestyle` setting in psql in an (obviously) **different connection**, that does not proof anything. You app may be setting a different `datestyle` in connection with local settings. You would have to check the setting inside your actual connection (not from psql).

If your datestyle setting is `'iso, mdy'`, then it should work as you want it to: date literals are interpreted *month-before-day*. Consider this demo (using PostgreSQL 9.1):

```
db=# set datestyle = 'ISO, MDY';
SET
db=# select '1.12.2012'::date;
    date
------------
 2012-01-12
(1 row)

db=# set datestyle = 'ISO, DMY';
SET
db=# select '1.12.2012'::date;
    date
------------
 2012-12-01
(1 row)
```

Emphasis mine.

To find out, which options are actually set by your app, you can set

```
log_statement = all
```

in your `postgresql.conf` and reload. Then start your app and save a date. Every single command will be logged. Don't forget to reset and reload afterwards (or your log files may grow huge):

```
log_statement = none
```

Then check your db log files what your app actually sent to the database.

---

You may also be interested in the [`to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) command, that lets you input date literals in any format you like. But you shouldn't need that.

Comment: I did `show datestyle;` in psql and got ISO, MDY, so it looks like that's already correct.

Comment: Checking in `psql` in a different connection hardly proofs anything. I added some more info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems as the original poster.  Since I have to compare dates/times against each other I did not want to change the DB fields to strings because that would require additional code and conversions later.

I ended up using before_save and attr_accessor in my model like this:

```
before_save    :format_date
attr_accessor  :unformatted_date

def format_date
  self.inquiry_date = Date.strptime(self.unformatted_date, "%m/%d/%Y").to_time(:utc)
end
```

The line in my view looks like this:

```
f.text_field  :unformatted_date, :value => (@foo.inquiry_date.blank? ? '' : @foo.inquiry_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y)), :id => 'datepicker'
```