# Rails 3 Date format in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

My question is similar to this SO problem, but it does not answer my question:

[Rails 3 default datetime format without UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694352/rails-3-default-datetime-format-without-utc)

I understand that I can add

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y/%m/%d"
```

to my `environment.rb` and it will change my default time format accordingly.

So when I do `Time.now.to_s` I get the correct format.

However, my question is, how come this does not work with a form_builder. For example:

```
<%= f.text_field :date %>
```

will return a full UTC timestamp: `2013-01-25 07:45:21`

I am aware that I can do this

```
<%= f.text_field :date, :value => @post.date.to_s %>
```

And it will give me the correct format.

But this solution seems hacky to me. Is this really the only way to do it?

Comment: How would you like your input to look like? The Rails [date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) helper is really flexible to customize and might fit your needs better than a text-field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure. But the answer is most likely no. The rails formhelper just gives you whatever value that is in your database.

Here is where the value is retrieved for your reference:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/InstanceTag.html#method-i-to_input_field_tag

There is no special processing of it, such as `localize` or `to_s`, which is where formatting is applied.

Answer (score -1):

If the date looks like a `timestamp` (`2013-01-25 07:45:21 UTC`),

You could do something like the following to views you localize timestamps with:

```
<%= localize(@post.date, :format => :long) %>
```

According to your problem, you could try using `date_select` rather than `text_field.`

```
<%= f.date_select :date, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the answer he is looking for. He is specifically asking how to get the correct format using the form builder.