# Specify format for Date object identified as a symbol in an form in erb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, erb

I need to specify the format of a date object I'm passing as a symbol in a form in erb.

With the following two lines:

This line causes an error:

```
<%= e.text_field :from_date, value: event.from_date.to_s, {class: "eventStartDate"} %>
```

This line does not:

```
<%= e.text_field :from_date, {class: "eventStartDate"} %>
```

I believe the first line will display my date correctly, as evidenced by this thread: [Rails 3 Date format in forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517571/rails-3-date-format-in-forms)

Why is this version giving me an error?

The error:

rails server

```
ERROR: compiling _app_views_planners__edit_event_html_erb___606087105846834961_70190839785020 RAISED ~/app/views/planners/_edit_event.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
..._s, {class: "eventStartDate"} );@output_buffer.safe_concat('...
...                               ^
~/app/views/planners/_edit_event.html.erb:33: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'); end ;@output_buffer.to_s
       ^
```

Line 14 of the partial `_edit_event_html_erb`

```
<%= e.text_field :from_date, value: event.from_date.to_s, {class: "eventStartDate"} %>&ndash;<%= e.text_field :to_date, {class: "eventEndDate"} %>
```

Line 33 is the end of the file.
    <% end %>

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `{}` of the class. `value` and `class` should be in same hash.

```
<%= e.text_field :from_date, value: event.from_date.to_s, class: "eventStartDate" %>
```